# Isomorphism theorems to conclude that cokernel is finite dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, quotient-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Are the following implications correct:
let $U,V$ be two subspaces of $H$ then
$$
     \frac{H}{U} = \frac{U+V}{U} \cong \frac{V}{U \cap V} \text{  and  } \frac{H}{V} \cong \frac{H}{U \cap V } \Big/ { \frac{V}{U \cap V} \cong \frac{H}{U \cap V}} \Big/  \frac{H}{U}. 
$$
Is this enough to show that if $U$ and $V$ have finite codimension, so has $U \cap V$?
Why does this not imply
$\operatorname{codim}U+\operatorname{codim}V=\operatorname{codim}(U \cap V)$?

Comment: You can't factor $H/U$ out of $H/U\cap V$ since it's not a subspace.  As to the third question: you seem to be  forgetting about the dimension of $X/U+V$.

Comment: Thanks! I understand it now. Basically the last isomorphism is not correct, but even without it the finiteness of codimension is implied, since the algbraic complement of say $V$ in $H$ is isomorphic to $H/V$.

Comment: You have edited the question to change it substantially. Originally the whole space was $X$, not $H=U+V$. It will now be the case that the final equality of codimensions is true.